# IP Camera IC (PAL to Ethernet)

Tags: ethernet, camera, video, ntsc, gigabit

I have a design problem to capture CCIR/PAL video from the camera that is available and send it over ethernet. Need to come up with my own printed circuit board design, having no prior experience in video processing.

Looking around for IP cameras over the internet, I saw an IP camera for only 35$. So I thought, there must be cheap ICs readily available that do this job (so no need to dive into FPGA/MCU software solutions for this task).

However I cannot find any IC specifically for this. Either I don't know the right terminology to search for it or there is no easy solution without writing my own embedded software that samples and compresses video and sends it through UDP or TCP. If its the second one, then I think 35$ product including the cheap camera is very competitive. I have no big price or competitiveness concern, it is only a thought.

---

RTD1186 and RTD1185 might be solution examples to what I am asking; but I am not sure; since Realtek does not put much info on their website.

Comment: So, do you actually have a question? If you read the help, you'll know that shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: The missing keyword in your searches may be "codec". Try http://www.ti.com/lit/ml/sprt585a/sprt585a.pdf

Comment: If you want to know what's inside a cheap IP camera, why not buy one and crack it open? Better yet, look for someone who's [already done it](https://jelmertiete.com/2016/03/14/IoT-IP-camera-teardown-and-getting-root-password/)

Comment: @RogerRowland It is not a shopping question, if you read it carefully I am only asking if the technology that I think that exists, actually exists or not. In my opinion there is a big difference in technology if for this task a time consuming FPGA design process is needed instead of using a readily available IC.

Comment: I have designed such beasts and you will need a video encoder and some sort of glue and control logic (a perfect fit might be an FPGA that incorporates an ARM core).

Comment: You might also try googling "video encoder"

Comment: There are various DSP chips that will do this, although you'll have to get the software; TI's examples use TMS320DM365. As far as I know there aren't non-programmable video-to-IP chips, most manufacturers want the programmability.

Comment: Probably the kind of thing you are looking for is an SoC (System on Chip). There's a bunch of firmware associated with this sort of thing, shop around and you can probably find it supplied in a reference design. As you've found the info is usually not very accessible since they are really not interested in small quantity sales (less than many, many thousands of pieces).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just taken apart a low cost IP camera made by Dahau and it appears to be based on a SoC made by Ambarella, part number S2L-M-A1-RH. Details are [here](https://www.ambarella.com/uploads/docs/S2Lm-Product-Brief-Final.pdf). The SoC includes just about everything you need to make an IP camera:

- ARM A9 processor
- camera front end video processor
- AES cryto engine
- H.264 video encoder
- Ethernet MAC

Most of these IP cameras run a version of Linux, and a Linux SDK is availabel for this SoC.

From past experience of trying to use parts like this, unless you are prepared to place an order for 100,000 the manufacturer probably won't be interested in talking to you.